# Sharepoint Email Prior to 8 weeks of target date

Tags: email

I want to create a SharePoint workflow on a list.
In such a way that a notification will be sent to the owner of the task ("Assigned To" field) every week starting at least 8 weeks in advance of target mitigation date?

Could you please suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer workflow:

Create 8 variables that are the desired date minus x amount of time

If status != completed then send email to [current item: assigned to]
Pause until variable: week 8

Repeat 8 times with corresponding pauses

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have setup a workflow based on your suggestion.I have one question
1)When we edit an existing event, the workflow running on the event will abort and new workflow starts?

Comment: Sounds like you should check when/how you have the workflow being initiated.